# Definir seções em um programa de reconhecimento de cor

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy, visão-computacional

Estou elaborando um projeto, que ano que vem virará meu TCC. Estou aprendendo por conta a linguagem do Python, e por enquanto já tive alguns avanços. Fui ler sobre visão computacional, porém ainda tenho algumas dúvidas.
Consegui formalizar um programa (após muitas video aulas em ingles kk) que exibe o video da Webcam, e faz o tracking de qualquer objeto com a cor azul. Estou com dificuldade em, neste mesmo programa, definir seções. Estas seções seriam para localizar se uma peça entrou na "casa" ou não. Utilizarei isto para um jogo da velha, por isso preciso definir uma seção de 3x3 (realmente um # na tela) e com isso consegui identificar se um objeto entrou ou não nesta casa.
Segue o código que tenho por enquanto. Caso alguem tenha alguma ideia de como fazer isso seria de grande ajuda!

```
import cv2   
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    ret, img = cap.read()

#converter imagem(img i.e BGR) para HSV (hue-saturation-value)

hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#definir dimensão da cor Azul
blue_lower=np.array([99,115,150],np.uint8)
blue_upper=np.array([110,255,255],np.uint8)

#encontrar as dimensões da cor Azul
blue=cv2.inRange(hsv,blue_lower,blue_upper)

#transformação e processamento  
kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")

blue=cv2.dilate(blue,kernal)
res1=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = blue)

#Tracking da cor azul
(_,contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(blue,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area>300):
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.putText(img,"Blue color",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255,0,0))


cv2.imshow("Cor",img)   
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
if k==27:
    break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```